# How to update row using only date without time in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is:

```
UPDATE SHIPMENT 
SET   PRODCODE='LAN', 
      SHIPQTY='39.54',
      REMARKS='MR BOPL',
      MISEQ='-1',
      SITEID='MR',
      SSEMPNO='31111110',
      S_GAUGE='412.54', 
      E_GAUGE='389.50',
      DENSITY='800',
      TEMPERATURE='40.30',
      TEMPATEND='40.30',
      SEDATE=TO_DATE('10-Jul-2018 12:00 AM','dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MI AM'), 
      WEIGHT_S='705.12',
      WEIGHT_E='665.58',
      SEEMPNO='31111110',
      TANKNO='1001' 
WHERE KEYSEQ='60719' 
  AND SSDATE=TO_DATE('09-Jul-2018 12:00 AM','dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MI AM');
```

There are 2 rows with same date with different time but I want to update both rows using only `'09-Jul-2018'` in where condition. Is it possible?

Comment: Why are all your numeric values in single quotes? Are they really being stored as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need:

```
AND trunc(SSDATE) = TO_DATE('09-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy');
```

or, better

```
AND trunc(SSDATE) = date '2018-07-09'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WHERE KEYSEQ='60719' 
  AND SSDATE >= TO_DATE('09-Jul-2018','dd-Mon-yyyy') 
  AND SSDATE < TO_DATE('09-Jul-2018','dd-Mon-yyyy') + 1;
```

thiw will update all rows with date `09-Jul-2018` and `KEYSEQ='60719'`